# Unexpected Positioning of Paragraphs When Small Capped Letters Do Not Follow the Lettrine

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, small-caps, lettrine, octavo

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass[foolscap]{octavo} % to get a small image
\usepackage{lettrine,lmodern,xcolor}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

\input GoudyIn.fd
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}

\fboxsep=0pt % padding thickness
\fboxrule=0pt % border thickness

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.30,findent=.21em,nindent=2.5pt]{\fcolorbox{black}{blue!35}{T\kern-.04em}}{his} is an example of the use of a lettrine where the letters following the lettrine appear in small caps. All is fine.

\vspace*{7pt}

\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.30,findent=.21em,nindent=2.5pt]{\fcolorbox{black}{blue!35}{A\kern-.04em}}{} lettrine where there are no letters to be displayed in small caps. Notice the difference in the spacing of the two displays.

\vspace*{7pt}

\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.30,findent=.21em,nindent=2.5pt]{\fcolorbox{black}{blue!35}{A\kern-.04em}}{} lettrine where there are no letters to be displayed in small caps. Notice the spacing between the lettrine itself and the word "lettrine".

\vspace*{7pt}

\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.30,findent=.21em,nindent=2.5pt]{\fcolorbox{black}{blue!35}{A\kern-.04em}}{} lettrine where no letters are displayed in small caps. Notice again, that in the previous example, the spacing between the lettrine itself and the word "lettrine" immediately following was off. But now it's fine.

\vspace*{7pt}

\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.30,findent=.21em,nindent=2.5pt]{\fcolorbox{black}{blue!35}{A\kern-.04em}}{} lettrine where there are no letters to be displayed in small caps. Notice again, that in the previous example, the spacing between the lettrine itself and the word "lettrine" immediately following was off. But now, in this paragraph, all again is \emph{not} fine.
\end{document}
```

which produces the output:

[image]

Notice that in the *first* of the five paragraphs, where there **are small-capped letters** following the lettrine --- all seems to be fine.

In the *second* paragraph, the `A' lettrine constitutes a word, and so there **are no small-capped letters** following it. Compared with the first paragraph, we see that the spacing of the entire paragraph has been slightly increased.

The *third* paragraph, which is longer than the previous two, has shifted the word "lettrine" farther to the right than before, yet a similar phenomenon does not occur in the lines that follow.

In the *fourth* paragraph, things seem to be back to normal.

Alas, when we increase the length of the paragraph a little in the *fifth* example, things seem to revert back to what they were in the third example.

QUESTION: Can anyone point out why these discrepancies might be occurring and how I might prevent such things from happening, so that when I have no small-capped letters following the lettrine, all might be displayed as in the first paragraph?

Comment: I don't see anything unexpected? Certainly nothing I'd call Bizarre?

Comment: @David Carlisle Sorry. Poor wording on my part. Hopefully now, the revised title better reflects the occurrences.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and especially about the `\unskip` comment. I see that that produces what I asked for---"as in the first paragraph".  I don't want to modify the question any further because once I did that a while back, and someone became quite annoyed. But if I may, let me ask you that if I wanted the output to resemble the second paragraph---what's the best way to do that? An `\unskip` followed by a positive `\hskip` perhaps? Thank you again.

Comment: note Ive changed my answer to suggest other things than unskip

Comment: you changed "bizarre" to "inconsistent", but of course it is very consistent, it is obeying the standard tex justification rules. It is your expectation that isn't matching the rules, not that something different is happening here.

Comment: Point well taken @David Carlisle.

Comment: Yet again you have changed your question without any indication of what you have changed, thus making nonsense of @DavidCarlisle first comment. Please have some thought for others. And no I'm not being rude just trying to help you.

Comment: @Peter Wilson Kind Sir, please read the litany of comments in their order, and you might see that two changes were made to the title in light of David Carlisle's comments. Moreover, with you in mind, I politely inquired of him in the comments (not the question) about the possibility of having all the output of paragraphs 3-5 resemble the second paragraph instead of the first---and Mr. Carlisle graciously complied---with an updated answer, though a comment would have sufficed for me. I hope this is a satisfactory response to your concern.

Comment: @Peter Wilson I expect to shortly delete my portion of our comment string from the post you alluded to. I think that they do not add in a positive way to the post, and I respectfully invite you to do similarly.

Comment: @Peter Wilson My friend, it seems that somebody has already, thankfully done that for us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's really related to having small caps or not just that any change anywhere in the paragraph, removing a word adding a comma,  ...  can change the line breaking in the whole paragraph.

The difference between
`T{his} is`
and
`A{} lettrine`
is that you get a word space after the dropped-cap+ empty argument so in loose lines it is a larger space.

On the word space before lettrine, compare  a normal word space, a fixed unstretched word space or no space

[image]

from

`}{A\kern-.04em}}{} lettrine`

`}{A\kern-.04em}}{}\mbox{ }lettrine`

`}{A\kern-.04em}}{}lettrine`

Comment: Many thanks @David Carlisle.

Answer (score 3):

If the second mandatory argument to `\lettrine` you want to use a kern instead of a space and this kern should be the same amount as `nindent`. Next you want to ignore the possible following spaces.

A kern doesn't participate in justification and its size is fixed. The space following the first word instead does, but of course when the second argument (the first word except for the initial), you don't want it participates in justification.

Now you clearly see the need for a macro doing all the job.

```
\documentclass[foolscap]{octavo} % to get a small image
\usepackage{lettrine,lmodern,xcolor}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

\input{GoudyIn.fd}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}
\newcommand{\LTR}[2]{%
  \lettrine[
    lines=3,
    loversize=0.3,
    findent=0.21em,
    nindent=2.5pt,
  ]{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \colorbox{blue!35}{#1\kern-0.04em}%
   }{#2}%
   % now we fix the problem with an empty argument
   \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
     \kern2.5pt\ignorespaces
   \fi
}

\begin{document}

\LTR{T}{his} is an example of the use of a lettrine where the letters 
following the lettrine appear in small caps. All is fine.

\vspace*{7pt}

\LTR{A}{} lettrine where there are no letters to be displayed in small 
caps. Notice the difference in the spacing of the two displays.

\vspace*{7pt}

\LTR{A}{} lettrine where there are no letters to be displayed in small caps.
Notice the spacing between the lettrine itself and the word ``lettrine''.

\vspace*{7pt}

\LTR{A}{} lettrine where no letters are displayed in small caps. 
Notice again, that in the previous example, the spacing between 
the lettrine itself and the word "lettrine" immediately following 
was off. But now it's fine.

\vspace*{7pt}

\LTR{A}{} lettrine where there are no letters to be displayed in small caps. 
Notice again, that in the previous example, the spacing between the lettrine 
itself and the word "lettrine" immediately following was off. But now, 
in this paragraph, all again is \emph{not} fine.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @egreg for posting this answer; as well as for your most helpful comment within an answer of yours a little while back regarding the kerning issue with my ill-formatting of, for example, `{\'{e}}`.

Answer (score 1):

As your question shows up again today, I hope I am not too late to add some comments.

First, the package `lettrine` accepts now (v. 2.30 released 2022/09 and 2.40 released yesterday) the same options as the `\lettrine` command, so your MWE can be simplified a little, but that's not the main point.

If you want the same layout as in the first example you can code `\lettrine{...}{lettrine}` instead of having an empty second argument, redefine `\LettrineTextFont` to get rid of the small caps and then play with options `findent` and `nindent`:

```
\documentclass[foolscap]{octavo} % to get a small image
\usepackage{lmodern,xcolor}   
\usepackage[lines=3, loversize=.30, findent=.21em,
            nindent=2.5pt]{lettrine}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

\input{GoudyIn.fd}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}
\fboxsep=0pt % padding thickness
\fboxrule=0pt % border thickness

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lettrine{\fcolorbox{black}{blue!35}{T\kern-.04em}}{his}
is an example of the use of a lettrine where the letters
following the lettrine appear in small caps. All is fine.

\vspace*{7pt}
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{} % No small caps

\lettrine{\fcolorbox{black}{blue!35}{A\kern-.04em}}{lettrine}
where there are no letters to be displayed in small caps.
Notice the difference in the spacing of the two displays.

\vspace*{7pt}

\lettrine{\fcolorbox{black}{blue!35}{A\kern-.04em}}
{lettrine}  where there are no letters to be displayed in
small caps. Notice the spacing between the lettrine itself
and the word "lettrine".

\vspace*{7pt}

\lettrine[findent=0.5em,nindent=0pt]{\fcolorbox{black}{blue!35}{A\kern-.04em}}{lettrine}
where no letters are displayed in small caps. 
Notice again,  that in the previous example, the spacing
between the lettrine itself and the word "lettrine"
immediately following was off. But now it's fine.

\end{document}
```

You get this as output:
[image]

The last paragraph shows a different layout, in case you  prefer all lines to be left aligned. Having the second argument close to the first makes sense when they are part of the same word (i.e. This) , probably not otherwise (A alone).

`findent` fixes the distance between the first and second mandatory argument of `\lettrine`, `nindent` fixes the *additional* skip for the next lines. You loose these tuning options when you make the second argument empty.

Comment: +1 Thank you for adding this.